# Sort the ements in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array in javascript called 'environment' .

I wish to sort this array based on the length of the ids of the elements . 
I am doing this as follows :

```
   for (i = 0; i < environment.length; i++) { 
    console.log(environment[i]['id']);
    // prints dev,production,staging ... I want it to be dev,staging,production
}
```

How can I achieve this ? 
TIA :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Try implementing quicksort as an exercise: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/

Answer (score 3):

```
environment.sort(function(a, b){return a.id.length > b.id.length})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `environment.sort()`.